# How to convert Array (ResultSet JDBC) to List?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, collections

I wrote code that should take a record from a database table by record ID. One of the columns of the table (record) is the collection of the student object. **How can I pull students out of a record and “fold” it into a List collection?**

Code:

```java
public Group findObjById(final int id) {
        Group group = new Group();

        try {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `course_work`.`group` WHERE `group_id` = " + id + ";");

            while (rs.next()) {
                int innerId = rs.getInt("group_id");
                List<Student> students = rs.getArray("students");
                group = new Group(innerId, students);
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return group;
    }
```

There is error on line 10 (102th line in *.java). 
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49fdG.png)
<-

**List.copyOf** and **Arrays.asList** DIDNT HELP (because it is not default array).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try casting the result array to a list like this `List<Student> students =  (List<Student>) rs.getArray("students");`

Comment: Works as "Unchecked cast".

Comment: @Mykola You accepted an answer that doesn't work at all, `ResultSet.getArray(String)` returns an instance of `java.sql.Array`, rather use `java.sql.Array.getArray()`, `java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Object)` and `java.lang.reflect.Array.get(Object, int)`or Felix's solution depending on which features are supported by your JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have made myself a simple utility method for `java.sql.Array` types:

```java
    /**
     * Collects an SQL-Array using the given collector
     * @param array
     * @param valueRetriever
     * @param collector
     * @param <T>
     * @param <A>
     * @param <R>
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static <T, A, R> R readArray(Array array, ResultSetValueRetriever<T> valueRetriever, Collector<T, A, R> collector) throws SQLException {
        final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator = collector.accumulator();
        final A container = collector.supplier().get();

        if (array != null) {
            try (ResultSet rs = array.getResultSet()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // 1 => index, 2 => value
                    // because we iterate ordered already, we only care about the value (2)
                    accumulator.accept(container, valueRetriever.get(rs, 2));
                }
            }
        }

        return collector.finisher().apply(container);
    }

    /**
     * Functional interface representing one ResultSet-Method to get the value of a column<p>
     * For example:<p>
     * <pre>
     *     ResultSetValueRetriever<String> getString = ResultSet::getString;
     *     ResultSetValueRetriever<Integer> getInt = ResultSet::getInt;
     * </pre>
     * @param <T> return type
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ResultSetValueRetriever<T> {

        T get(ResultSet rs, int index) throws SQLException;
    }
```

Usage:

```java
// jdbc index starts at 1
// the first column of your resultset is an array => rs.getArray(1)
// ResultSet::getInt is used to retrieve items from the array column 
// -> if its an array of ints, use ResultSet::getInt
// -> if its an array of strings, use ResultSet::getString
final List<Integer> ints = readArray(rs.getArray(1), ResultSet::getInt, Collectors.toList());

// you can also use this to collect arrays of arrays etc
// for example, to collect an array of array of strings:
final List<List<String>> strings = readArray(
    rs.getArray(1),
    (subRs, index) -> readArray(subRs.getArray(index), ResultSet::getString, Collectors.toList()),
    Collectors.toList()
);
```

It now depends on the data inside the column `students`. Is it an Array of Strings? And what does your `Student` class look like ?

Comment: Student - object with fields: name, surname, address, telphone number (strings) and id and age (ints). I think, it will be good idea to override toString() just for name+surname and output it.

Comment: @MykolaMurza and what does the data inside your field ```students``` (in your DB) look like ?

Comment: columns (INT and VARCHAR). I'll get List of ID's, problem solved, thanks)